# Считается ли хорошим вариантом создавать объект внутри его класса?

Tags: java, ооп, классы

Привет!  Я начал глубже разбираться в классах и их взаимодействии.

Я решил создать маленькую программу, которая содержит:

- класс test(который содержит метод main);
- User(который содержит информацию о пользователе, геттеры и сеттеры для логина и "пароля" для пользователя);
- Menu(В этом классе пока существует один метод, который использует геттеры и сеттеры класса User, задает ему имя и пароль, такая себе регистрация);

Класс User содержит в себе такой код:

```
public class User {
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public static User user = new User();

    public void setName(String name){
        userName = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return userName;
    }

    public void setPassword(String pass){
       password = pass;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

}
```

Когда я создавал обьект пользователя в классе Menu, в методе register, где после этого и присваивал ему никнейм и пароль, я заметил, что я не смогу использовать этот объект в других методах и классах, ибо чтобы обратится к нему и получить никнейм, я должен был бы написать, к примеру в классе test: `Menu.user.getName()`  , но работать это не будет.

Поэтому я создал объект в том же классе, где находятся его сеттеры и геттеры. Теперь, если я хочу обратиться к объекту User, у которого название, к примеру, user

( User user = new User(); )

с любого уголка программы, я просто пишу `User.user.setName("John");`

Считается ли это хорошей практикой, создавать объект в его же классе, (потому-что иначе я пока не знаю, как к нему обратится из другого метода или класса)? Если существует правильная альтернатива, как она должна выглядеть?

Буду рад **каждому** совету, даже если он будет о моем ужасном коде или непонимании, я приму каждый совет, я уважаю мнение каждого пользователя!

Upd.: тот единственный метод в классе Menu:

```
public class Menu {

public static void register(){


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Create your nickname:");
        User.user.setName(sc.nextLine());
    }while(User.user.getName().equals(""));

    do {
        System.out.println("Create your password:");
        User.user.setPassword(sc.nextLine());
    }while(User.user.getPassword().equals(""));
}
```

}

Comment: Зачем вам создавать объект Юзер внутри класса Меню?

Comment: мне почему-то казалось логичным такой вариант. Якобы если используется метод регистрации, то его результатом должен стать новый пользователь. Добавил тот метод из класса Menu в вопрос.

Comment: Просто интересно, должно ли всё так быть. Всегда, когда я писал какие-то программы и смотрел на самые простые примеры, объект класса создавался в другом классе, а не его "родном".

Comment: Вы запутались. Новый пользователь уже создается в ``User user = new User();``. Если вы имеете в виду регистрацию нового пользователся в базе (суда по имени метода register), то перенесите этот метод в класс Юзер.

Comment: "объект класса создавался в другом классе" - в яве все создается и исполняется в классах. Даже ``Hello World`` без класса не напечатать :)

Comment: Спасибо! Да, бывает иногда, что рациональный и адекватный вариант приходит в голову не всегда, когда его использование очевидно :)

Comment: @NazariiKlymok логично в таком случае синглтон использовать

Comment: Привет, Санаев! Я сегодня уже встречался с синглтоном в другом вопросе. Мне показалась проблема знакомой. Парадоксально, что я не знаю, что это :) (ЗЫ не надо делать круглые глаза, как понятно по вопросу, я изучаю Java)
Я точно знаю, что это как-то связано с тем, что в классе должен быть лишь один экземпляр(объект). Я обязательно узнаю больше об этом. Спасибо за комментарий!

Comment: Я так понял, что сиглтон - это то что и нужно было для выполнения этой задачи.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Краткий ответ на ваш вопрос - зависит от обстоятельств. В конкретно вашем случае - это **очень** плохая практика.

Теперь детальнее. Строкой

```
public static User user = new User();
```

вы создаете **единый** глобальный объект на всю систему. Обычно такие объекты обозначают некоторые константы, как, например, `BigInteger.ONE` или некоторые интерфейсные объекты. Т.е. объекты не хранящие свое внутреннее состояние, а выполняющие только какие-то действия.

Но в любом случае, такие объекты создают с модификатором `final`, чтобы предотвратить возможность перезаписывания их в любом месте программы

```
User.user = null;
```

В вашем же случае нужно четко представлять область видимости объекта и предоставлять соответствующий уровень доступа. Если вы пишете

```
public static void register(){
  .........
  User user = new User();
  .........
}
```

то такой объект будет виден (и существовать) только в этом методе. Может быть, вам нужно вернуть его из метода

```
public static User register(){
  .........
  User user = new User();
  .........
  return user;
}
```

и тогда пусть вызывающая сторона заботится о его существовании. В том числе отдает всем заинтересованным в нем объектам. С учетом того, что метод `register` у вас статический, мне это видится самым адекватным решением.

Еще есть вариант сделать этот объект статическим полем класса `Menu` (но зачем в меню пользователь для меня загадка)

```
class Menu {
    private static User user;
    public static User getUser() {
      return user;
    }
    public static void register() {
      .........
      User user = new User();
      .........
    }
}
```

в этом случае мы опять получаем единый глобальный объект, но уже без возможности его перезатирания (но по прежнему остается возможность его несанкционированной модификации)

Также можно объявить метод `register` нестатическим. Тогда и объект будет нестатическим, а обычным полем класса со всеми возможностями первого способа. Но повторюсь - адекватность связи меню и пользователя у меня вызывает сомнения.

Comment: Спасибо Антон! Вы ответили на мой вопрос и конкретно объяснили ситуацию. Действительно, создавать Юзера в методе register было довольно глупо, так как тогда он будет виден лишь для метода register. Если мне будет нужно, могу вернуть нужные мне данные юзера с помощью return. Благодарю, что расставили точки над моими сомнениями и развеяли туман непонимания)) Если я, конечно, всё правильно понял :)

Comment: Также, хотелось бы узнать: Если я возвращаю с помощью метода public User getUser(){ return user; }, то как я могу получить из возвращенного юзера его параметры?

Comment: @NazariiKlymok Да собственно так же, как и для любого другого объекта `User usr = getUser(); System.out.println(usr.getPassword());` или сразу `System.out.println(getUser().getPassword())`

Answer (score 5):

Идеологически `Menu` вряд ли состоит из `User`, но скорее всего использует его для своей работы, то есть это *зависимость*. Зависимости лучше внедрять извне, тогда можно будет добавить ссылки на `User` в любой объект, который от него зависит.

Пусть:

```
public interface AbstractUser {...}
public class StandardUser implements AbstractUser {...}
public class SpecialUser implements AbstractUser {...}
```

Внедрять зависимости можно через конструктор (когда `Menu` **требует** для своей работы `User`)

```
public class Menu {
    public class Menu(AbstractUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    private AbstractUser user;
}

...
var user = new SpecialUser();
var menu = new Menu(user);
...
```

или через поле/сеттер (когда зависимость **опциональна** и/или существует подходящий **умолчательный вариант**).

```
public class Menu {
    public class Menu() {
        this.user = new StandardUser();
    }

    public void setUser(AbstractUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    private AbstractUser user;
}

...
var menu = new Menu(); // uses StandardUser as default impl.
var user = new SpecialUser();
menu.setUser(user); // switch to optional impl.
...
```

Comment: Спасибо, free_ze, что рассказали и объяснили, что такое зависимости! По идее, мне нужно будет использовать параметры Юзера только в некоторых случаях. Например, если в меню будет функия изменения никнейма или пароля, ну или, просто обратиться к пользователю с помощью его никнейма. По-этому, тут скорее всего можно воспользоваться геттерами, а Юзера создать в классе User, и там же задать ему логин и пароль.